# Uniform distribution, as a sum of biased Bernoulli trials.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Suppose that the probability of $x=0$ is $p$, and the probability of $x=1$ is $1-p=q$. Consider the random sequence $X=\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. We map this sequence by $C$ to a point in the interval $[0,1]$ as below:

$1)$ we look at the first random variable. If it is $0$, then we update the interval to $I_1=[0,p)$, else update it to $I_1=[p,1)$.

$2)$ Let $I_k=[a,b)$. Look at the $(k+1)^{th}$ random variable. if it is $0$, then we update the interval to $I_{k+1}=[a,a+p(b-a))$, else we update it to $I_{k+1}=[b-q(b-a),b)$.

and we continue this process till we reach to a point as the length of the random process goes to infinity. As an example if the first $2$ random variables are $01$, then we have:

$I_1=[0,p)$

$I_2=[p-qp,p)$.

Find the pdf of $C(X)$.

Comment: You first need to show that the limit of the sequence of intervals converges a.s.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 ok. then?

Comment: Then you know its actually a random variable...or is this a homework problem/textbook problem and so you are assuming the limit exists?

Comment: this is one of the problems of previous examinations

Comment: Ah I see...wasn't sure if you just came up with this sequence or not...I'll give it some thought and answer if I have something. If you had developed this sequence yourself, then existence would need to precede any other proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, we observe that probability of $C(X)$ being inside an interval (for example $[p,1)$) is proportional to the length of the interval.

Notice that $C(X)$ is not well defined for $p=0,1$. So let us assume $0<p<1$. Define new random variables $Y_{i}=p(1-X_{i})+qX_{i}$. Then $Y_{i}=p$ with probability $p$, and $Y_{i}=q$ with probability $q$.

Observe that $C(X)$ can also be written as 
\begin{eqnarray}
C(X)=pX_{1}+p\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}X_{k}Y_{i}.
\end{eqnarray}

Basically $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}Y_{i}$ measures the length of the intervals at $(k-1)th$ step. If $p=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}Y_{i}=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$, otherwise it depends on the position of the intervals and previous $X_{i}$s.

Now let us pick a $x\in[0,1]$. There is a unique sequence of numbers $\{x_{i}\}$ such that 
\begin{eqnarray}
x=px_{1}+p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}x_{k}y_{i},
\end{eqnarray}
where $x_{i}\in\{0,1\}$ and $y_{i}=p(1-x_{i})+qx_{i}$ for all $i$. We want to find $\mathbb{P}(C(X)\leq x)$.

Let $s=\{s_{i}\}$ be a sequence of numbers from $\{0,1\}$, and $k$ be the first position where $s$ differs from $x$.  In other words, $s_{i}=x_{i}$ for all $1\leq i< k$ and $s_{k}\neq x_{k}$. Notice that we have $C(s)\leq x$ only if $s_{k}\leq x_{k}$. But if $x_{k}=0$, then $s_{k}\leq x_{k}$ implies that $s_{k}=0$ i.e., $s_{k}=x_{k}$. In other words, $s_{k}$ can not differ from $x_{k}$ if $x_{k}=0$. So the only possibility is $x_{k}=1$ and $s_{k}=0$. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(C(X)\leq x)&=&\sum_{k: x_{k}=1}\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=x_{i}\;\forall\;1\leq i\leq k-1, X_{k}\neq x_{k})\\
&=&px_{1}+p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}x_{k}y_{i}\\
&=&x.
\end{eqnarray}
Consequently $C(X)\sim U[0,1]$.

Comment: Can you explain more how did you derive the first expression for $C(X)$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be written as $C(X)=pX_1+q\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}X_kY_i$?

Comment: No, for example if $X_{1}=0$ and $X_{2}=1$, then we should be in the interval $[p^{2},p)$ (you have already mentioned this fact in your question). The main idea is that at $kth$ step if $X_{k}=1$, you are adding $p$th proportion of the existing interval $[a,b)$ and $C(X)\in [a+p(b-a),b)$(as you have mentioned in (2)). And the length of the existing interval is given by $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}Y_{i}$. For example, when $k=2$, the previous intervals were $[0,p)$ and $[p,1)$. Lengths of those intervals are exactly the values of $Y_{1}$. If $X_{1}=0$, $C(X)$ falls in $[0,p)$ which has length $p=Y_{1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Indrajit. You helped me so much. You are genius

Answer (score 1):

At the $n$th step, $I_n=J$, where $J$ is one of $2^n$ disjoint intervals whose union is $(0,1)$. Each of these intervals $J$ has length $p^kq^{n-k}$ for some $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$ and the probability that $I_n=J$ is $p^kq^{n-k}$. This holds for every $n$ hence $C(X)$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I cannot figure out how did you conclude that $C(X)$is uniformly distributed. Can you explain more?

Comment: Sure, which part of the solution *before its conclusion* do you fail to get?

Comment: your conclusion. you said that since the last relation holds for every $n$, hence $C(X)$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$. I cannot understand how did you derived this conclusion from probability of $I_n$.

Comment: The distribution of $C(X)$ gives to each of these intervals a probability which is its length. The intervals generate the Borel sigma-algebra hence the distribution is the Lebesgue measure on (0,1).

Comment: @AMIR since you got this from a previous test, I doubt the testers were expecting a long, drawn-out demonstration. The simple observation that the probability of being in an interval, $P(C(X)\in I)$ is proportional to the length of $I$ (i.e., $\lambda(I)$ is all you need to form your conclusion. Often the best answers are the shortest, as they substitute understanding for raw calculation. Keep that in mind as you prepare for your test or studies.